# Not able to connect Gitlab Repositry with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gitlab, version-control

I am not able to fetch my Gitlab repository with my Intellij Idea. Due to this, I'm not able to push my code into my repository. Git is installed on my laptop. Can anyone please help me to fix my problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcpR5.jpg)

I am trying to connect my Gitlab repositry with my Intellij IDEA but the connection is not building.

Comment: The path to the git executable is just that -- the path to the `git` program on your computer. It is not the location of the remote repository. You can type `which git` to find the location.

Answer (score 2):

1. The place where you pasted URL is for git executable, not for the git repository.
2. If you want to clone - please proceed with "Get from version control"
3. Otherwise, if you have a project created and repository created in GitLab - please add remote under Git | Manage remotes